# NodeJS | Access send Data on finish event

Tags: node.js, typescript, server

How can I access the send data on the nodejs `finish` event?

I send some JSON data like this:

```js
oResponse.json({
    version: "1.0.0",
    author: "Someone",
    contributors: "also Someone"
});
```

And i want to access these data on the `finish` event of the nodejs server like this

```js
oResponse.once("finish", async (): Promise<void> => {
    console.log("print the json here");
});
```

But how is it possible to print the send data in the finish event? Do i need to do some steps in between? Or isn't it possible?

Comment: `oResponse.body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a middleware to do it

```
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const resJson = res.json;
    res.json = function(data) {
        res.body = data;
        res.json = resJson;
        return res.json(data);
    }
    next();
  });
```

and then

```
oResponse.once("finish", async (): Promise<void> => {
    console.log(res.body);
});
```